# Posting a whole project, ready for public review

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, code-length

Say I have an open source project hosted on GitHub or wherever, currently in the public review, testing, and bug reporting phase.

The [Asking](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page says:

> ...feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project...

That tells me that it must be a `piece of code` not a whole project. But I don't see why a whole project under review wouldn't be acceptable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read that entire section, you see:

> If you are looking for feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project in the following areas…
>
> - Best practices and design pattern usage
> - Security issues
> - Performance
> - Correctness in unanticipated cases
>
> then you are in the right place!
>
> However, if your question is not about a particular piece of code and instead is a generally applicable question about…
>
> - Best practices in general (that is, it's okay to ask "Does this code follow common best practices?", but not "What is the best practice regarding X?")
> - Tools, improving, or conducting code reviews
> - How to add a feature to or solve a problem with your code
> - Trouble-shooting, debugging, or understanding code snippets
> - Higher-level architecture and design of software systems
>   then your question is off-topic for this site.

Now what that basically means is that you can post a small, or large, portion of a project. Hell, you can post the whole thing.

What that disallows:

> - My project is structured like the following, is that acceptable?
> - Are there any bugs in this code that you see?
> - Why did this not pass code review?
> - Are there any missing tests here?

We review *the code itself*, not the general ideas. We **may** comment on the general ideas, but it's **not** a requirement. You can ask things like:

> - Here is all the code for my project, I'm wondering if the class `X` is doing things the best manner possible.
> - Here is all the code for my project, it's intended to be run in a high-concurrency environment so any critique in that area would be welcome.
> - Here is all the code for my project, it's currently in the bug / testing / public review phase, how does the code here look?

These are all asking for a broader code review on the project, some of them have *specific concerns in mind*, which is acceptable, provided you're not asking about bugs, missing tests, how to add feature `Y`, etc. Do note, this does **not** mean *any* reviewers will address those concerns, each review is in-and-of-itself an answer to '*is this code the best possible code, can it be made better?*', which is the implied question for **all questions on this site.**

Lastly, I'm not sure if you're aware or not, but Stack Exchange [has *very kindly* helped us with *this exact issue*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101038/implementation-of-stddeque-obsolete#comment184668_101038). Code Review is (I think) the only Stack Exchange site that [has a 65536 character limit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101038/implementation-of-stddeque-obsolete#comment184710_101038).

And because those comments *may* be deleted in the future:

> I just upped the `MaxBodySize` limit, so you should be able to have the whole code in the question body. For Code Review, I believe it's important to have all the code in one place. :-) – [Chris Jester-Young](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/216/chris-jester-young) [Aug 15 '15 at 15:41](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101038/implementation-of-stddeque-obsolete#comment184668_101038)
>
> More seriously, the limit has been raised to 65536 from 30000. – [Chris Jester-Young](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/216/chris-jester-young) [Aug 15 '15 at 18:20](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101038/implementation-of-stddeque-obsolete#comment184710_101038)

---

So, tl;dr: you can post the whole project, you can have specific concerns, make sure those concerns are on-topic and *do not* be upset if reviewers ignore those concerns entirely.

I hope to see your question soon, and I hope you get great reviews on it! :)